# How to identify a string and print line in a file in java?

Tags: java

I am Java beginner and I am trying to find a word in the file and print out the line where it exists.
 My file looks like:

```
dog  one 100.11
cat two 200.22
doggg  four 400.44
```

And if I input "dog", the output should be

> dog  one 100.11

But currently I have an error the word is not found.

Please Help! Thanks!

```
File file = new File("G:\\Eclipse\\src\\test.txt");
Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Input:");
String name = input.next();
while (s.hasNext()) {
  String line = s.nextLine();
  String name = s.next();
  if (name.equals(name)) {
    System.out.println(line);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use a HashMap.

Declare your HashMap as

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Then, go through your string and add the first word to the map.

```
while (s.hasNext()) {
    String current = s.nextLine();
    String[] currentWords = current.split(" ");
    map.put(currentWords[0], current);
}
```

Then, when you read the string, simply put

```
System.out.println(map.get(line));
```

Answer (score 0):

To find if there is single word in sentence use `contains()`

```
if (name.contains(input)) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Right now you are checking if `dog` is equals to `dog  one 100.11`

In case you have more then one line who can fit `dog` you can split the sentence and check if the first string matches

```
String[] words = line.split(" ");
if (words[0].equals(input)) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: But then if I input dog it will print out dog and doggg

Comment: Yes your codes work! Thank you! And I will try to implement it into a bigger program.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected one.

```
File file = new File("G:\\Eclipse\\src\\test.txt");
Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Input:");
String in = input.next();
while (s.hasNext()) {
    String line = s.nextLine();
    if (line.contains(in)) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Guy's solution gives you "doggg  four 400.44", too.
Just add a " " to the input.

```
if (name.contains(input + " ")) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Although this is quite inefficient, it works for a small programm.

However, this also finds 
"heres a text dog one 11111"
and wont find
"one 100.11 dog"

EDIT:
Just saw, Guy's edit.
His solution is better.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code needs yet another `while` loop to scan each word in a line

```
// Get user input
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Input:");
String name = input.next();
// Get lines from file
File file = new File("G:\\Eclipse\\src\\test.txt");
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file);
while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
  String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
  // scan each word in a line
  Scanner lineScanner  = new Scanner(line);
  while (lineScanner.hasNext()) {
    String word = lineScanner.next();
    if (name.equals(word)) {
      System.out.println(line);
      break; // we done with the current line
    }
  }
}
```